# Component not being rendered in switch statement in onChange Listener

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. I have a class called **GroupSelectt**. In this class I have a switch statement in the onChange listener for a Select dropdown menu. When a selection is made I want a different form to render for each dropdown selection., i.e conditional rendering using a switch statement. ADCform and NVMform are currently identical in code.My issue is that the forms do not render on screen. I'm unsure if this is the correct way to do it or if there is a more efficient way.Below are my code files. Thanks

**GroupedSelectt.js**

```
import { borderBottom } from '@mui/system';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import ListSubheader from '@mui/material/ListSubheader';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import { ADCform } from './ADCform';
import { NVMform } from './NVMform';
/* eslint-disable */

const options = ["peter", "bob", "bill"]


export class GroupedSelectt extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "peter",
  };



  onChange = e => {

    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    var vap = e.target.value
    console.log(vap)
    switch (vap) {
      case 'peter':

        break;
      case 'bob':
        <NVMform/>
        break;
      case 'bill':

      <ADCform/>
        break;
      default:
        return 'foo';
    }

  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;


    return (

      <div>
        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 1200 }}>

          <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-select">Category</InputLabel>

          <Select id="options" value={value} onChange={this.onChange}>

            <ListSubheader >Name Options</ListSubheader>

            {options.map((val, index) => <MenuItem key={index} value={val}> {val} </MenuItem>)}

          </Select>

        </FormControl>


      </div>



    )
  }
}
```

**ADCform.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import './CSS/Home.css';
import {  Form, Col, Row, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';



export class ADCform extends React.Component{
render(){
    return (
    <div>
    
        <Form>

  
    <Row className="mb-3">
    <Form.Group as={Col}>
      <Form.Label>Fruit</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="ms" placeholder="Enter Fruit" />
      <br></br>
    </Form.Group>

    
    <Form.Label htmlFor="inputPassword5">Enter Drink</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control
    type="percentage"
    id="inputPassword6"
    aria-describedby="Test"
  />
  </Row>

    </Form>
  </div>
    );
    }
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import './CSS/Home.css';
import { Card, Form, } from 'react-bootstrap';



import { GroupedSelectt } from './GroupedSelectt';
import { ADCform } from './ADCform';




export class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (

      <div>

        <Card className='cardSize'>

          <Form className='formWidth'>
            <Form.Label className='label'>Category</Form.Label>
            <GroupedSelectt />

          </Form>

        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are just starting to learn react, I recommend learning with functional components and hooks instead of class components. You can find more in-depth discussions about this online, but the two main advantages IMO are that functional components are less verbose, and hooks give you more granular control than lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the following:

```
import { borderBottom } from '@mui/system';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import ListSubheader from '@mui/material/ListSubheader';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import { ADCform } from './ADCform';
import { NVMform } from './NVMform';
import { Card, Form, } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './CSS/Home.css';
/* eslint-disable */

const options = ["peter", "bob", "bill"]
var component = null;


export class GroupedSelectt extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "peter",
  };



  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    var vap = e.target.value;
    switch (vap) {
      case 'peter':
        return;
      case 'bob':
        component = <NVMform />;
        break
      case 'bill':
        component = <ADCform />;
        break
      default:
        return 'foo';
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;


    return (

      <div>
       
          

            <FormControl sx={{ m: 5, minWidth: 1200, Height: 1200 }}>

              <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-select">Category</InputLabel>

              <Select id="options" value={value} onChange={this.onChange}>

                <ListSubheader >Name Options</ListSubheader>

                {options.map((val, index) => <MenuItem key={index} value={val}> {val} </MenuItem>)}
                

              </Select>
              {component}
            </FormControl>
         
       

      </div>



    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the forms in your switch cases for them to be able to be rendered in the JSX, like so:

```
onChange = e => {
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  var vap = e.target.value;
  switch (vap) {
    case 'peter':
      return;
    case 'bob':
      return <NVMform />;
    case 'bill':
      return <ADCform />;
    default:
      return 'foo';
  }
};
```

I see another problem, you are not rendering the components anywhere in the JSX. For this to work you'd need to call it in the JSX, something like:

```
<div>{onChange}</div>
```

But this doesnt make sense. What i'd do is move this logic to another function called renderForm:

```
renderForm = e => {
  switch (this.state.value) {
    case 'peter':
      return;
    case 'bob':
      return <NVMform />;
    case 'bill':
      return <ADCform />;
    default:
      return 'foo';
  }
};
```

And then call it in the JSX like explained above. Then modify your onChange component to just change the state:

```
onChange = e => {
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
};
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: I have tried this and I pasted the above into my file and it still does not render the forms?

Comment: Updated the comment.